# Подсчитать процент значения каждого элемента в списке

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика

Есть некий список с возрастающими данными: `[30, 42, 49, 50, 65, 104, 420, 404, 513, ...]`.

Задача: подсчитать в процентном соотношении размер (ширину) каждого значения (элемента) в списке. Список может динамически пополняться новым значением при помощи `.push()`.

Например:

- Есть список: `[100, 100]` - получаем размер значений: `[50%, 50%]`
- Добавляем новое значение: `.push(200)` - `[100, 100, 200]`
- Получаем: `[25%, 25%, 50%]`
- Добавляем значение: `.push(400)` - `[100, 100, 200, 400]`
- Получаем: `[12.5%, 12.5%, 25%, 50%]`

И так далее.

Если непонятно описал задачу или есть какие-то вопросы - пишите, дополню свой вопрос.

Comment: Вы что нибудь сами пробовали? Просто готовый ответ получить это не интересно

Comment: Что вы пробовали сделать, что у вас не получается?

Comment: Не сердитесь на меня, я не программист, а всего лишь фермер.

Comment: Товарищ фермер, это никак не отменяет требований к нормальному формулированию вопросов.В текущем виде вы описали расплывчатое ТЗ, а не задали вопрос. Вероятно за это его и минусуют. Учтите на будущее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать функцию для этого:

```
function toPercentages(list) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        total += list[i];
    }
    return list.map(function(x) {
        return parseFloat((x * 100 / total).toFixed(2));
    });
}
```

Использование:

```
> var list = [100, 100];
> toPercentages(list);
[50, 50]
> list.push(200);
> toPercentages(list);
[25, 25, 50]
> list.push(400);
> toPercentages(list);
[12.5, 12.5, 25, 50]
```

Comment: Я бы не пересчитывал каждый раз список заново, а хранил бы его сумму и при пуше сразу же бы имел сумму.

Comment: @MaxZS ну у него уникальный метод для любого массива, который ты туда пропихнешь. Выгодней считать сумму каждый раз

Comment: @MaxZS А вдруг изменение не пуш?

Answer (score 0):

```
function procArr(arr){
    var sum = 0;
    var procArray = [];
    $.each(arr,function(key,value){
        sum += value;
    });
    $.each(arr,function(key,value){
        var proc = value/sum* 100;
        procArray.push(proc);
    });
    return procArray;
}
```

Узнаем сумму считаем процент от неё

```
procArr([100, 100]);
[50, 50]
```

Comment: Чтобы сложить несколько чисел не обязательно подключать jQuery. Ваш хуже

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев согласен, по привычке быстро написал. Переписывать не буду ниже есть варианты.

Answer (score 0):

Сумму считать сразу, для просчёта процентов использовать `Array.map()`:

```js
function Widther(){
  var arr, sum;
  if( arguments.length === 0) {
    arr = [];
  } else if( arguments.length === 1) {
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) === '[object Array]') {
      arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0]);
    } else if( !isNaN(parseFloat(arguments[0])) && isFinite(arguments[0])) {
      arr = [ arguments[0]];
    } else arr = [];
  } else arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  sum = arr.reduce( function(p,c){ return p+c;});

  return {
    push: function(e){
      arr.push(e);
      sum += e;
    }
    
    ,getArray: function(){
      return arr;
    }
  
    ,getPercent: function() {
      return arr.map( function(e){ return 100*e/sum; });
    }
  }
}

function clog(str) { document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + str; }
function alog(arr) { clog( JSON.stringify(arr)); }

var W = new Widther( 100,100);
alog( W.getArray());  //  [100, 100]

alog( W.getPercent());  //  [50, 50]
W.push(200);
alog( W.getPercent());  //  [25,25,50]
W.push(400);
alog( W.getPercent());  //  [12.5,12.5,25,50]
```

Upd. усложнил, лишь бы конструктор принимал аргументы в угоду @Grundy )

Comment: тот момент, когда `new` ничего не значит и его можно не использовать :)

Comment: тот момент был между прошлым и будущим, и уже закончился – обновил ответ )

Comment: а смысл `new` так и не появился:) если уберешь его - ничего не поменяется :Р

Answer (score 0):

Вот тогда и мой вариант, раз уж написал.

**Создать объект можно так:**

`var s = new Percentage([50, 100, 150] [, log = true])`

По стандарту логирование включено (Выключить путем ввода, второго параметра = `false`)

**Использовать:**

`s.array` - выведет текущий массив

`s.calculated` - переведенный в проценты массив

`s.set([100, 200, 400])` - заполоняет объект новыми данными

`s.push(10000)` - вставляет в существующий объект число

**Код:**

```js
(function (window) {
  var Percentage = function (array, log = true) {
    this.array = array;
    this.needLog = log;
    this.calculated = this.calc();
    if (this.needLog) console.log(this.calculated);
    return this;
  }

  Percentage.prototype.set = function (array) {
    return this.constructor(array, this.needLog);
  }

  Percentage.prototype.push = function (number) {
    this.array.push(number);
    this.calculated = this.calc();
    if (this.needLog) console.log(this.calculated);
    return this;
  }

  Percentage.prototype.calc = function (number) {
    var total = 0,
        i = this.array.length;
    while (i--) total += this.array[i];
    return this.array.map(function(x) {
      return parseFloat((x * 100 / total).toFixed(2));
    });
  }
  
  window.Percentage = Percentage;
})(window);

// Пример использования
var s = new Percentage([5, 10, 15, 50, 100]);
s.set([200, 300, 500, 1000]);
```